# Initializing Views using a method

Tags: android, view, initialization

I wonder if it's possible to make a method in a class, to initialize all my views?

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
public class MyInitialize extends View{


    public MyInitialize(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    public void iniViewByID(View view[], int id[]){

        for(int x=0; x<view.length; x++){


            view[x] = findViewById(id[x]);
        }

    }
```

USAGE:

```
MyInitialize myInitialize = new MyInitialize(this);
View myViews[] = new View[]{btn,txtview};
int myIDs[] = new int[]{R.id.btn,R.id.txtview};

myInitialize.iniViewByID(myViews,myIDs);
```

But it didn't work for me so I don't know if that's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it didn't work for me so I don't know if that's not possible.

Edit:

MyInitialize.java

```
public class MyInitialize extends View {


    public MyInitialize(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    public View[] iniViewByID(Context mContext, View view[], int id[]) {

        for (int x = 0; x < view.length; x++) {


            view[x] = ((Activity)mContext).findViewById(id[x]);
        }
        return view;

    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
    TextView txtview = null;
    Button btn = null;

    int myIDs[] = new int[]{R.id.btn, R.id.txtview};
    View myViews[] = new MyInitialize(this).iniViewByID(this, new View[]{btn, txtview}, myIDs);

    ((Button) myViews[0]).setText("Worked");
    ((TextView) myViews[1]).setText("Worked");
```

Comment: it works like this only if the method was made inside the same activity, if i make a separate class then it will never work u can try it , i will update my post

Comment: Do you want to access these views from other activity?

Comment: no , i just want to make a separate class that includes these methods to make my onCreate much cleaner

Comment: Check out my update, you need to specify which `Context`:)

Comment: wow funny thing is that i made an mContext at first then i forgot to use it then deleted it from my class lol , thank you Paul good answer!

Comment: if u have time let me know if there any trick to use btn instead of myviews[0] : )

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of creating another class for initialising views. Just create a function in your MainActivity class and call that function in onCreate method. Then initialise the views in the created function.

You can also check [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) API to initialise Views easily.